# Как скрывать содержимое div'a при нажатии вне его области?

Tags: html

Вот собственно сам div:

```
<div class="nav-miniprofile-content" style="display: none; min-width: 130px;">
```

Надо чтобы при нажатии на другое место (вне его области) это окошко закрывалось.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

В JavaScript вы можете подписаться на событие например тега  `body` и при клике на `body` убирать видимость `div`. При этом вам необходимо подписаться на клик самого `div` и выполнить там `event.stopPropagation()` чтобы клик по `div` не проводил клик до body. Хорошая практика не забывать убирать после закрытия `div` слушателя на `body`